# ModuleNotFoundError NLTK

Tags: python, python-3.x, nltk

Tokenization is working fine but when I try to do Named Entity Recognition
namedEnt = ne_chunk(tagged, binary=True)

It gives the following error
I did install the NumPy from cmd using pip install numpy but still giving the error

```
import nltk
from nltk.corpus import state_union
from nltk.tokenize import PunktSentenceTokenizer, word_tokenize
from nltk.chunk import ne_chunk

train_text = state_union.raw("2005-GWBush.txt")
sample_text = state_union.raw("2006-GWBush.txt")
# print(train_text)


custom_sent_tokenizer = PunktSentenceTokenizer(train_text)
tokenized = custom_sent_tokenizer.tokenize(sample_text)


def process_content():
    for i in tokenized:
        words = word_tokenize(i)
        tagged = nltk.pos_tag(words)
        namedEnt = ne_chunk(tagged, binary=True)
        print(namedEnt)


process_content()
```

Error:

```
PS D:\Python\nltk> & C:/Users/Talha/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37/python.exe d:/Python/nltk/nltk_task.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:/Python/nltk/nltk_task.py", line 64, in <module>
    process_content()
  File "d:/Python/nltk/nltk_task.py", line 60, in process_content
    namedEnt = ne_chunk(tagged, binary=True)
  File "C:\Users\Talha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\nltk\chunk\__init__.py", line 185, in ne_chunk
    chunker = load(chunker_pickle)
  File "C:\Users\Talha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\nltk\data.py", line 757, in load
    resource_val = pickle.load(opened_resource)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'
```

Comment: did you install numpy in the same environment in which you are running your script?

Comment: @luigigi  yes, I think so

Comment: @luigigi but I am not using NumPy apparently then it is giving this error..Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

Install numpy by `pip install numpy` then import it by `import numpy as np`